# have problem on sides of buttons or seekbar side

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am developing a music player app, but I have a problem: as you can see from the two pictures below from two phones, in some devices, the sides of the seekbar are at the wrong side, and the buttons switch place. What could the problem be?

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_rew"
    android:onClick="priviusclick"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView9" />
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Screenshots are identical

Comment: Check what happens when the play button is pressed. As in the second screenshot, it is in a play state, there the previous/forward buttons are mirrored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As look at the screenshot and it is clear that it is mirror. This is just because you may have use `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your manifest.xml file inside `application`, This will support for Right to left layout when device has RTL language set. So just change it to `false` value like this:

```
  <application
   
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    >
```